# Change form parameter based on form selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have 3 different forms on a single page where the user can switch between using JS. The forms represent different information and only one can be submitted at a time where the user is then redirected to a different page based on the form they selected. The issue is that I have 2 input fields that are common to these forms so they are outside the forms. I am able to submit them alongside a form if I set the :

```
<input id="default" form="form1">
```

value.

So I figured it would be a simple thing to just add a function in each script where I hide/show the forms to also change that parameter to the form I want submitted however it doesn't seem to work.

```
function form2Search() {
        $('#form2Section').show();
        var input1 = document.getElementById('default');
        input1.form = "form2";
    }
```

I have something like this but it doesn't change the form parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setAttribute

```js
function form2Search() {
        $('#form2Section').show();
        var input1 = document.getElementById('default');
        input1.setAttribute("form", "form2");
        console.log(input1.getAttribute("form"))
    }
    
    form2Search();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="default" form="form1">
```

---

Comment: `input1.form = 'form2'` is fine, in vanilla JS, which oddly OP is mixing with jQuery *(which I wouldn't use these days)*.

Comment: then explain me why isn't this working https://jsfiddle.net/abj9kz5x/

Comment: You can't append any attribute like that. You should know this. You can only do these for known attributes such as style, width,height  @StackSlave

Comment: I guess it's not used enough that they lived up to normal web standards. `Element.attribute =` should always work. I'm going to consider this something Browser developers should fix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually give your input an ID of `default` so you can target it:

```
<input form="form1" id="default">
```